# "Table 'users.my_aspnet_Sessions' doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I am using MySQL session state provider for ASP.NET membership. I used the MySQL website configuration utility in configure the session state provider and the tool went ahead and created the following schema:

Tables_in_users

```
my_aspnet_applications
my_aspnet_membership
my_aspnet_profiles
my_aspnet_roles
my_aspnet_schemaversion
my_aspnet_sessioncleanup
my_aspnet_sessions
my_aspnet_users
my_aspnet_usersinroles
```

The issue it that the automatic session cleanup utility keeps throwing the following exception:

An exception occurred communicating with the data source.

```
Action: CleanupOldSessionsException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'users.my_aspnet_Sessions' doesn't exist
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore.DeleteTimedOutSessionsWithCallback()
   at MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore.DeleteTimedOutSessions()
   at MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore.CleanupOldSessions(Object o)
```

The exception is entirely valid, 'users.my_aspnet_Sessions' indeed doesn't exist. Is there a way to get around is issue? Have I missed something in configuration?

I have already tried renaming the table but that produces other exceptions since other components of the connector still expect the current name.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have a separate database for the users and another one for your transactions? Or is everything in one database?

Comment: As of right now, everything is in a single table.

Comment: Having the same problem. In my case i know the cause, just missing the solution... My database is in a linux server, and therefor table names are case sensitive... MySQL creates a table named my_aspnet_sessions and somewhere in the provider tries to access it as my_aspnet_Sessions

Answer (score 2):

As I said on my comment, I had the same problem.

"Having the same problem. In my case i know the cause, just missing the solution... My database is in a linux server, and therefor table names are case sensitive... MySQL creates a table named my_aspnet_sessions and somewhere in the provider tries to access it as my_aspnet_Sessions"

The problem was caused by a bug in the mysql connector and it was fix in version 6.8.3(http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=450594).

Just install and change your state server provider version to "Version=6.8.3.0" and it should work just fine.